# Installing plugin manually in internet explorer plugin folder

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, plugins

I have to install an internet explorer plugin manually by this mentioned protocol:

> Manual Installation. If automatic installation failed you can install
>   plugin manually, for this: Click here to download and save this zip
>   file. Then unpack it into the plugins folder of your browser tree.
>   Restart the browser.

Where can I find that folder in WINDOWS 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Where is the Internet Explorer Plugins directory?

On Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit) the Internet Explorer Plugins directory is located at:

```
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\Plugins
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all download the .DLL file or .OCX file and then put it in on a folder.
Then open RUN -> cmd -> regsvr32 "...".
in the place of "..." (three dots) put the location of file (.dll or .ocx) along with its name and extension.
Then Press ENTER.

It will register the add on file. For example see the picture, given below:

Comment: There is no picture below...?

Comment: I guess new user can not upload a photo, can the new user?